# geom_point will not accept 0 as a value

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a graph showing measured values with the mean and 95% CIs for a given group among the points. R keeps telling me it has removed rows with the value  0 and therefore the remainder of the points are off.

The code I'm using is:

```
data.summary <- data %>%
  group_by(condition, conc) %>%
  summarise(
    sd = sd(score, na.rm = TRUE),
    score = mean(score))    
ggplot(data, aes(condition, score, color=concentration)) +
      geom_jitter(aes(color=conc),position = position_jitter(0.2)) + 
      expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
      scale_color_manual("Conc",breaks = c("4", "5", "6", "7"), 
                         values=c("sienna1", "dodgerblue1", "green1", "deeppink1"))+
      new_scale("color")+
      geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = score-sd, ymax = score+sd, color=conc),data = data.summary) +
      expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
       scale_color_manual("Conc",breaks = c("4", "5", "6"), 
                         values=c("sienna4", "dodgerblue4", "green4", "deeppink4")) +
      ggtitle("Data")
```

Data (dput format):

```
structure(list(hydra = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), 
    time = c(72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
    72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
    72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
    72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
    72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
    72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
    72L, 72L), condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Control Bisection", 
    "Control Decapitation", "Treatment Bisection", "Treatment Decapitation"
    ), class = "factor"), conc = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), score = c(9L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 
    0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
    0L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-72L))
```

This is what the data should look like, vs what I am getting

[image: What I should see]
[image: What I see]

Comment: could you provide an example of the data you are using? dput(data)

Comment: Just added to the post

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately, I still can't regenerate fully the data dataframe with it. Did you copy the full console output of dput(data)?

Comment: I added the extended version - I wasn't able to add it previously - apologies!

Comment: where does `new_scale` come from?? (OK, I found it in the `ggnewscale` package.)  Where does `data.summary` come from? It's really useful to have a [mcve] ...

Comment: data.summary <- data %>%
  group_by(condition, conc) %>%
  summarise(
    sd = sd(score, na.rm = TRUE),
    score = mean(score))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things about your code that don't work as expected, but I think the primary issue is that in this line:

```
scale_color_manual("Conc",breaks = c("4", "5", "6", "7"), 
            values=c("sienna1", "dodgerblue1", "green1", "deeppink1"))
```

you haven't specified a value for what to do if the concentration is zero. This works (I don't think you actually want black points, but you can change the first colour however you want):

```
brkvec <- as.character(c(0, 4:7)
colvec <- c("black","sienna1", "dodgerblue1", "green1", "deeppink1")
scale_color_manual("Conc",breaks = brkvec, values = colvec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the credit goes to @Ben but you may find this simpler...

```r
library(ggplot2)

mydata$conc <-  factor(mydata$conc)


brkvec <- as.character(c(0, 4:7))
colvec <- c("black","sienna1", "dodgerblue1", "green1", "deeppink1")

ggplot(mydata, aes(condition, score, color=conc)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color=conc),position = position_jitter(0.2)) +
  expand_limits(x = 0, 
                y = 0) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = score - sd(score, na.rm = TRUE), 
                      ymax = score + sd(score, na.rm = TRUE))) +
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
  scale_color_manual("Conc", breaks = brkvec, values = colvec) +
  ggtitle("Data")
```

[image]

Comment: Glad it worked please mark an answer correct.  I'm perfectly happy if Ben gets the nod.